# Using Map function for gvlma in R

Tags: r, function, purrr

I have the following linear model regressions and have created a list called regression_list. Now I am trying to use the map function to run gvlma instead of one by one like this gvlma(m1_vtv). Have written this function and am getting error.

```
m2_vtv<-lm(vtv~retailsales+cpi, data=df_final)
m3_vtv<-lm(vtv~retailsales+cpi+tmf, data=df_final)
m1_vug<-lm(vug~retailsales, data=df_final)
m2_vug<-lm(vug~retailsales+cpi, data=df_final)
m3_vug<-lm(vug~retailsales+cpi+tmf, data=df_final)

regression_list<-c(m1_vtv,m2_vtv,m3_vtv,m1_vug,m2_vug,m3_vug)

regression_function <- function(x){
  reg<-(gvlma(regression_list))
}

tbl_data <- regression_list %>% 
  mutate(data = purrr::map(x, ~regression_function(.x)))
```

Comment: It's more difficult to help without a [mcve].  Please post a fully reproducible example.  From what you have posted, it looks like you are both trying to pipe `regression_list` into `mutate` into `map`...but then the function in `map`, `regression_function()`, invokes `regression_list` inside it.  This needs to be untangled.  Consider something like `regression_list %>% map(~regression_function(.x))`, and inside your `regression_function()`, use `x` instead of `regression_list`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach that passes in the formulas, rather than the fitted `lm` objects:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(gvlma)

n <- 100
df <- tibble(a = rnorm(n), b = rnorm(n), c = rnorm(n), y = rnorm(n))

formula1 <- formula(y ~ a + b)
formula2 <- formula(y ~ a + c)
formula3 <- formula(y ~ b + c)

formula_list <- c(formula1, formula2, formula3)

tbl_data <- formula_list %>% map(~gvlma(.x, data = df))

tbl_data
```

Output:

```
# first output only for demonstration
[[1]]

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ a + b, data = df)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)            a            b  
   -0.19082     -0.08452     -0.01623  


ASSESSMENT OF THE LINEAR MODEL ASSUMPTIONS
USING THE GLOBAL TEST ON 4 DEGREES-OF-FREEDOM:
Level of Significance =  0.05 

Call:
 gvlma(x = .x, data = df) 

                     Value p-value                Decision
Global Stat        2.85554  0.5823 Assumptions acceptable.
Skewness           0.01156  0.9144 Assumptions acceptable.
Kurtosis           0.24505  0.6206 Assumptions acceptable.
Link Function      0.03240  0.8571 Assumptions acceptable.
Heteroscedasticity 2.56653  0.1091 Assumptions acceptable.
```